# Android activity workflow framework

Tags: android, android-activity

My app consists of a series of steps (Activities) that the user must complete each time the app is started. Being in a specific step, it is not allowed to go the next step unless certain criteria are fulfilled in the current step, for example text fields have been filled.

I am looking for an Android framework to help me manage these situations. Specifically, it would help to define Activities as "states" and would allow to specify (in a declarative way) the conditions that must be fulfilled in order to go the the next state(s), i.e. implement a "finite state machine".

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use fragments in a case like this. It's pretty easy to manage fragments via the fragment manager and you can easily implement going back and/or adding the next step when needed.